# vs code terminal externally on when i run javascript code in node js and cannot show output

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, terminal, nodes

In my vs code when I write javascript and then I clicked run or write node main.js the vs code terminal externally on the new window cannot show any output.

In visual studio code settings I turned off window conpty setting and visual studio code preference settings but It cannot fix. So, How I can run code internally in vs code terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "gnode" you seem to be running, is not part of the official distribution of NodeJS. Someone similar with your problem (https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3670), found a solution by uninstalling whatever he had installed, and reinstalling the LTS version of node (https://nodejs.org/en/download/).